# Angular pattern validation on form control fails until you edit the field

Tags: angular

I have an Angular project, and in it there is a reactive form. Two of the fields accept a manually entered date of the format 'dd/mm/yyyy'. When creating a new item using the form, the validation works perfectly. But, when I set the values on the form using `patchValues`, the pattern validation on the two date fields fails. If however, you remove a character from the date and re-enter it, the validation passes.

I'm creating the form like this;

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
      id: new FormControl(''),
      active: new FormControl(false),
      name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      availableFrom: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/g)]),
      availableTo: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/g)]),
      fuelTypes: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      position: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      linkUrl: new FormControl('', [this.urlValidator, Validators.pattern(urlPattern)]),
      imageUrl: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      reference: new FormControl(''),
      advertiser: new FormControl(''),
      tenants: new FormControl([], Validators.required)
    });
```

and updating the forms value in an `onEditAdvert` function;

```
onEditAdvert(advert: any) {
    this.form.reset();
    this.form.patchValue({
      id: advert.id,
      active: advert.active,
      name: advert.name,
      linkUrl: advert.linkUrl,
      imageUrl: advert.imageUrl,
      availableFrom: advert.availableFrom,
      availableTo: advert.availableTo,
      fuelTypes: advert.fuelTypes,
      position: advert.positionId,
      reference: advert.reference,
      advertiser: advert.advertiser,
      tenants: [...advert.tenants.map(item => item), 0]
    });
    this.form.get('availableFrom').updateValueAndValidity(); // Added to try and fix the issue
    this.form.get('availableTo').updateValueAndValidity(); // Added to try and fix the issue

    this.advertModal.show();
  }
```

So, it seems the values in the field, for example 01/01/2020 isn't valid when set via `patchValues`, but is valid if you manually enter it.

Can anyone shed any light on why this might be happening?

EDIT:

Just incase this is helpful. The values for the date are retrieved via an API, and the date values are converted to a string using this method;

```
public static DateStringToString(dateStr: string): string {
    const dateTime = dateStr.split('T');
    const parts = dateTime[0].split('-');

    return parts[2] + '/' + parts[1] + '/' + parts[0];
  }
```

The return value from this method is what is being set on the form fields.

The HTML for the form fields themselves is very simple.

```
<div class="col-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Start Date</label>
                <input type="text" formControlName="availableFrom" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>End Date</label>
                <input type="text" formControlName="availableTo" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
              </div>
            </div>
```

If I specifically specify the values to patch onto the form rather than getting the values from the advert object, I have the same issue.

```
availableFrom: '01/01/2020',
availableTo: '01/05/2020',
```

It seems like the problem is with the pattern that validates the string.

Comment: could you please put a working example link like from stackblitz it would be easy to check and answer.

Comment: When you patch are you putting in string literals dates like '01/01/2020'?

Comment: Can you add html code also?

Comment: yes, the values being patches are just strings, they're not dates.